# SQlite loads database from the wrong folder in c# on windows startup

Tags: c#, windows, sqlite, startup, registrykey

I get this error when app starts on windows startup but the app runs perfect when i open it while the windows is running .

```
SQLite error (14): cannot open file at line 47640 of [b0c4230c89]
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException' in System.Data.SQLite.dll
SQLite error (14): os_win.c:47639: (2) winOpen(C:\WINDOWS\System32\qubanga.db) - The system cannot find the file specified
```

This is the sqlite database connection the program uses to retrive the database .

```
 try
            {
               SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=database.db; Version = 3; New = True; Compress = True; ");
                sqlite_conn.Open();



                SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;
                
                string createTable = "Insert into " + table + "(" + columns + ") Values("+values+");";

                sqlite_cmd = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand();
                sqlite_cmd.CommandText = createTable;
                var query = sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
              
                if (query == 1)
                    result = true;

            }
```

Set StartUp for the program

```
 public  static void  SetStartup()
        {
            RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey
                ("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);

           
                rk.SetValue("AppName", Application.ExecutablePath);
           

        }
```

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***. also: have you made 100% sure that the file is present at the applications execution directory? have you tried running it with an absolute path? it's also a bit confusing - your connection string says `database.db`, your error message `qubanga.db`

Comment: *the program uses to retrive the database* - N insert statement does not retrieve anything, btw

Comment: Seems like your app is getting a working directory of the windows folder when it's launched at system startup. Perhaps it should locate itself eg ExecutablePath and use that to derive the db location /change its working directory to where the database is

Comment: @FranzGleichmann  I change the database name when writing this post

Comment: If you want to change [Application.ExecutablePath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.executablepath?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) you drag the exe to a different folder in windows

Comment: If your mean how to change the working directory, look at Directory.SetCurrentDirectory or Environment.CurrentDirectory

Comment: @CaiusJard,,noted

Answer (score 1):

If your application is in a different folder than the System32 folder (which I hope it is) your code will set the registry key to that folder path. Run regedit and navigate to that key to check. So on startup Windows will look to the Application folder for the db and not to the System32 folder. Try this to set it to the System32 folder instead.

```
rk.SetValue("AppName", Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System), "qubanga.db" );
```

Comment: It's easier to solve the issues this way

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

So After working on the problem with the solution provided above ,I realize that the program on Windows  start up was being executed from `C:\WINDOWS\System32\` instead of the location where it's installed .
I solved the issues by changing the Working Directory of the application .I got this Idea from @Caius

```
public static void SetWorkingDirectory()
        {
            string excePath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(excePath);
                //Console.WriteLine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());



        }
```